# call back function does not update handle

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback

I am using a callback function according to this code [callback function in gui does not know handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261835/callback-function-in-gui-does-not-know-handles)

However in the function that is called with the callback function I can not change data in the handle structure.

```
handles.waitbar.text = 'Reading images ...';
handles = readStackAndCreateFokusFunktion( ...
              handles , ...
              @(value, maxValue) ...
                    z_WaitBarUpdate(value, maxValue, handles));
```

In the function called I modify the handle, but this is not used in the function `z_WaitBarUpdate`.

```
function handles = readStackAndCreateFokusFunktion( handles, fcallback )

handles.waitbar.text = 'Extracting number of images in calibration file ...'; 
guidata(handles.output,handles);
% calls z_WaitBarUpdate as extpected, but the text is still 'Reading images ...'
fcallback(0, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple update of the handle in the callback function solved the problem:

```
function z_WaitBarUpdate(value, maxValue, handles)
handles=guidata(handles.output); % <- added
if ishandle(handles.waitbar.handle)
    waitbar(value/maxValue,handles.waitbar.handle,handles.waitbar.text);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you must update handles structure at the last

`guidata(handles.output);`